# Kohana Captcha module

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana, captcha

I'm trying to use [kohana-captcha module](https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-captcha) for a Kohana 3.3 project. Everything works fine until the validation.

The problem is that Captcha module always shows different answer no matter what image has been generated. Here is the example of my code:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = "template";

    public function action_create()
    {
            if (isset($_POST['captcha']))
            {
                print $_POST['captcha'];
                print ">>>".Captcha::valid($_POST['captcha'])."<<<";
            }

            $captcha = Captcha::instance();

            $this->template->content = View::factory('user/create')
                ->bind('captcha', $captcha);
    }
}

?>
```

View code:

```
<form method="post" action="/user/create/" class="form-horizontal" id="form">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputCaptcha">
            <?=$captcha?>
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputCaptcha" placeholder="Код с картинки" name="captcha">
          <span class="help-inline"></span>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

`$_SESSION and $_COOKIE` arrays are also empty.
The point is that I see the captcha image, enter the code, submit a form and then receive nothing. `Captcha::valid($_POST['captcha'])` shows me nothing. When I try to make `print_r($captcha)` after `Captcha::instance()` it shows me an object with a protected "response" property but it contains absolutely different letters and digits.

For example, I see an image with a "KX5R" captcha code, here is the result of print_r($captcha):

```
Captcha_Alpha Object ( [driver:protected] => [response:protected] => MWXF [image:protected] => [image_type:protected] => png )
```

Any advices?

Comment: I assume my issue is related to this one https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-captcha/issues/5 However, I don't know how to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your `POST` variable, in this case 'captcha', is equal to the instance of the Captcha. So you should initiate `Captcha` object before your `if` statement where you are validating `post`.

Something like this:

```
$captcha = Captcha::instance();

$this->template->content = View::factory('user/create')
    ->set('captcha', $captcha);

if ($this->request->method() === Request::POST)
{
    if (Captcha::valid($_POST['captcha']))
        .. do something if captcha is OK
    else 
        ..do something if captcha is not OK 
}
```